# The space of non-decreasing functions $f : \mathbb{R} \to [0,1]$ is compact.

Tags: general-topology

I'm working on the following problem.

Consider the set

$$
X = \{f:\mathbb{R} \to [0,1] \ | \ x \leq y \Rightarrow f(x) \leq f(y) \} \subset [0,1]^{\mathbb{R}}
$$

with the subspace topology induced from the product topology. Show that $X$ is compact.

I would like to get a hint on how to get started on this problem, as well I would like to know how the open sets "looks" like in $[0,1]^{\mathbb{R}}$.

**Edit**

From the comments and answer I came up with the following:

By Tychnoff its sufficient to Show that X is closed. Let $(f_i)_i$ be a net in X and assume that $f_i \to f$. We wish to prove that $f \in X \ \Rightarrow \forall U$ nbh of $f$, $(f_j)_{j\geq i} \in U$, where $U \supset \{g \in [0,1]^{\mathbb{R}} \ : \ |f(x) - g(x)| < \epsilon \}$.
Thus, assume $a<b$ then

$$
f(b) - f(a) \leq |f(b) - f(a)| \leq |f(b)-f_j(b)| + |f_j(b) - f_j(a)| + |f_j(a) - f(a)| \Rightarrow \\
f(b) - f(a) \geq 0.
$$

Comment: Important to note is that a basic open set in the product is only restricted in finitely many points.

Comment: I dont understand what you mean by "restricted in finitely many points". @HagenvonEitzen

Comment: If $U\subset[0,1]^{\Bbb R}$ is open, then there exist finitely many $x_i$, $1\le i\le n$ and open sets $U_i\subset [0,1]$ such that $U$ is the product of: $U_i$ in the $x_i$ component, and all of $[0,1]$ in all other components

Answer (score 1):

The product of cpmacts $[0,1]^{\Bbb R}$ is compact by Tychonov.
To show that the complement of $X$ is open, let $f\colon \Bbb R\to[0,1]$ be not non-decreasing. Then there exist $a<b$ with $f(a)<f(b)$. Let $c=\frac{f(a)+f(b)}2$. Then the set of all maps $g$ with $g(a)<c$ and $g(b)>c$ is an open neighbourhood of $f$ and disjoint to $X$.

Comment: Some of your $<$s and $>$s are the wrong way.

Comment: $a<b$ with $f(a) > f(b)$ and $g(a)>c, \ \ g(b) < c$?

Comment: Also if you can explain with a little more detail why the set would be open.

Comment: @Olba12 if we denote the projections by $\pi_x: [0,1]^{\mathbb{R}}$ defined by $\pi_x(f) = f(x)$ for any $ x \in \mathbb{R}$ then Hagen's set is just $\pi_a^{-1}[(-\infty, c)] \cap \pi_b^{-1}[(c, \infty)]$ which is a basic open set of the product $[0,1]^{\mathbb{R}}$

Answer (score 0):

By Tychonoff's theorem it is enough to show that $X$ is closed, but this is easily seen by considering a net $(f_\lambda)$ that converges to some $f$.

Comment: I gave your suggestion a go. Please look at my edit.

Comment: Not quite clear what you write. If $a < b$ you have $f_\lambda(a) \leq f_\lambda(b)$ for all $\lambda$. Then you can take on both sides the limit to see that $f(a) \leq f(b)$.

Comment: Yes, it's unclear. Thanks for the explanation.